# If it can't be null, but it needs to be initialized, what do I make it?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have a problem accessing some of my xpaths. We use a hybrid testing framework.

```
public class logoutMenu {
    public static void run(WebDriver driver) {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream selectproductsidebarobjectrepository;
        try {
            selectproductsidebarobjectrepository = new FileInputStream(
                    "C:/thisisthepath/ObjectRepositories/SignInPageObjectRepository");
            prop.load(selectproductsidebarobjectrepository);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            WebElement logoutNormal = driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("logoutnormal")));
            Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
            actions.moveToElement(logoutNormal).build().perform();
            WebElement logoutHover = driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("logouthover")));
            logoutHover.click();
            WebElement logoutPushed = driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("logoutpushed")));
            logoutPushed.click();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (selectproductsidebarobjectrepository != null) {
                try {
                    selectproductsidebarobjectrepository.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ORIGINAL PROBLEM**:
It tells me that the xpath cannot be accessed if it is null. It's null because of this line: `InputStream selectproductsidebarobjectrepository = null;`. If I take away the `= null;` part of it, I get a different error: "The local variable selectproductsidebarobjectrepository may not have been initialized" which also makes sense.

What can I make selectproductsidebarobjectrepository equal to that isn't null?

**NEW ISSUE**:
Cleaned up the code. Got rid of the null. Got rid of the extra bracket. Still coming up as:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find elements when the XPath expression is null.
at org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath(By.java:113)
at SelectProductSidebar.logoutMenu.run(logoutMenu.java:29)
at CommonFunctions.FunctionCheck.test(FunctionCheck.java:19)
```

Here is the script that calls this class:

```
public class FunctionCheck {
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        WebDriver driver;
        String baseUrl;
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl = "http://www.MATTDAMON.com/";
        driver.get(baseUrl + "MATT/MATT/MATT/MATT");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        LoginPage.enterValidCredentials.run(driver);
        SelectProductSidebar.logoutMenu.run(driver);
```

In case I'm screwing up a lot more than I initially though (probably true), here is the text file selectproductsidebarobjectrepository:

```
logoutnormal=//img[contains(@src,'log_out_normal')]
logouthover=//img[contains(@src,'log_out_hover')]
logoutpushed=//img[contains(@src,'log_out_pushed')]
```

I'm probably doing something really stupid but I'm absolutely blind to what it is right now.

Comment: why do you need to initialize it ? also you have extra braces after `InputStream selectproductsidebarobjectrepository = null;` It can be just `InputStream selectproductsidebarobjectrepository;` This should be a warning "The local variable selectproductsidebarobjectrepository may not have been initialized" not an error

Comment: @StackFlowed Because if I don't initialize it, I can't use it. Do you know any other methods of accessing it? Getting rid of the `= null` creates a new error. Error or warning, regardless, it won't compile and stops the test.

Comment: Your issue probably can be solved by using a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement… which also will make your code easier to read.

Comment: Taking away the initialization to `null` causes a failure due to your accessing it in the `finally` block. There's nothing wrong with your code as I see it though (except for the extra set of braces surrounding the body, which should be innocuous). If you're having problems, try pasting in actual error messages rather than your sanitized description.

Comment: remove the extra { after  = null;

Comment: As a side note- `selectproductsidebarobjectrepository` is a lousy name for a variable. use camel case, it will make it look much better: `selectProductSidebarObjectRepository` - see how much more readable it is?

Comment: Not only is that variable name lousy, the whole code is a mess. You are doing why to many things in that poor method.

Comment: @Jägermeister Learning. Is there anything inherently wrong with "doing too many things" in a method? The application under testing is horribly coded, I kinda don't have any other choice (as far as my knowledge goes).

Comment: @brightbomb Sure thing. Code is read many more times than written. So it should be **easy** to read. A method that does one thing typically is easy to read. The code that you posted ... is not. I recommend looking for "Clean code" by Robert Martin. Even for beginners - why not learn how to write **good** code while learning to program at the same point? Versus first learning how to program; and then after many years realize that there are very important practices that distinguish an average programmer from one that writes **good** source code?! (all imho)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me after removing the extra brace.

```
public class logoutMenu {
    public static void run(WebDriver driver) {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream selectproductsidebarobjectrepository;
        try {
            selectproductsidebarobjectrepository = new FileInputStream(
                    "C:/thisisthepath/ObjectRepositories/SignInPageObjectRepository");
            prop.load(selectproductsidebarobjectrepository);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            WebElement logoutNormal = driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("log_out_normal")));
            Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
            actions.moveToElement(logoutNormal).build().perform();
            WebElement logoutHover = driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("log_out_hover")));
            logoutHover.click();
            WebElement logoutPushed = driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("log_out_pushed")));
            logoutPushed.click();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (selectproductsidebarobjectrepository != null) {
                try {
                    selectproductsidebarobjectrepository.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So I took the advice, and used the above code. It is still coming up as "void". I'm going to update the original post, as well as post the test script that uses this class. Somethings weird here. One moment.

Comment: are you sure this is `selectproductsidebarobjectrepository = new FileInputStream("C:/thisisthepath/ObjectRepositories/SignInPageObjectRepository");` not null ?

Comment: With the absense of my name and company from the directory, yes, positive. My object repository for enterValidCredentials has the same format and works fine.

Comment: @StackFlowed new [AnyThing]() can never be null. It might throw a FileNotFoundException.

Comment: Oh my god. @StackFlowed You just saved my life. Nope. My directory was wrong and I was pointing at a different text file. I am so sorry, hahaha.